# How to make a textured tree model outside of unity that can be used in unity

Tags: unity, 3d, blender, 3d-meshes

So I am trying to make a 3d model of a tree that is textured that can be used in unity. So far I have tried two separate ways to do this and they both didn't work. The first time I used blender's tree creator add on to make a great looking tree but the textures for the tree needed to be applied in nodes and that doesn't transfer over to unity. The second time I used unity's own tree creator, but it's incredible hard to make a good tree with it and the textures I apply always get stretched and distorted to fit the tree making them blurry. So I really would appreciate if someone could tell me a good way to make trees that can be used in unity.

Thanks, nova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try tree[d]. It is an old program from frecle that allows you to create various trees. I believe the devs have stopped updating it and the download link is down. You can find it via the webarchive site [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130915030534/http://www.frecle.net/index.php?show=treed.about)